# Extrinsic parameters from OpenCV

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I'm using OpenCV to calibrate a stereo camera pair.  I've taken various calibration photos and I have a satisfactory fit for the intrinsic parameters using cv2.calibrateCamera.  However, it's not clear how to get the extrinsic parameters out.

The function just returns the cameraMatrix, which while useful is only half the story, as it were.  I'd like to be able to obtain the rotation/translation shown in the top of the documentation - i.e. a vector from the world origin to the camera perspective centre and a rotation.

I'm guessing cv2.solvePnP is something like what I need, but it's unclear exactly what R/T are - are they [R|t] in the projection formula or something else?

I realise that it's also possible to use cv2.stereoCalibrate, but I don't see why it's necessary to have two cameras.  In principle the projection matrix is obtainable for each camera individually.

Comment: R and T are 3x1 vectors describing the rotation and translation of your camera

Comment: Yep thanks, realised I asked a rather daft question here.

Comment: it happens to everyone.  If that is all you needed I will just put it as an answer

Comment: Well, it occurred to me that for a single camera asking what the translation/rotation is doesn't make much sense - may as well define the coordinates centred on the camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R and T are 3x1 vectors describing the rotation and translation of your camera

Comment: isn't R 3x3? a rotation matrix

Comment: @AnderBiguri There are a variety of ways of expressing a rotation.  The 3x1 vector is an axis angle notation where the direction of the vector defines the axis of rotation and its magnitude defines the magnitude of rotation.  cv::Rodrigues can convert that notation into a 3x3 matrix for you

Comment: Oh! I had completely forgot that, you are very rigth. Sorry

Comment: I have a question, how do we interpret the R and T of both the cameras? The R and T that we get are pose of the camera with respect to the checkerboard, right? but what if we want the R and T between two cameras?