# How can i obtain Camera Matrix in 3Dreconstruction?

Tags: python, opencv, matrix, camera, 3d-reconstruction

I want to achieve a 3D-reconstruction algorithm with sfm,

But how should i set the parameters of the Camera Matrix?

I have double cameras,both know their focal length.

And how about Rotation Matrix and Translation Matrix from world view?

i use python

Comment: have a look at http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d7c/tutorial_table_of_content_sfm.html and http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/dab/tutorial_sfm_trajectory_estimation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a code for camera calibration and printing a camera matrix in your OpenCV installation. Go to this path if you are on windows -

C:\opencv\sources\samples\python

There you have  a file called calibrate

Comment: yes,i found i can use camera calibration to get  it,but i don't have translation matrix and rotation matrix to create extrinsic matrix

Comment: Check This :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440198/extrinsic-parameters-from-opencv

Comment: what i'm thinking now is the matrices which i'd like to get (2 matrices R and t ) are to change the world coordinates to camera coordinates, not the R and t matrices which change the coordinates about camera1 to camera2,cv2.stereoCalibrate can only map the points of two camera

Comment: @Wang.J I don't think there is an OpenCV function to do that, but it's just matrix multiplications. Have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83578/464307).

Comment: @GabrielDevillers  thank for you, i've found that the extrinsic matrix is just to obtain camera2 intrinsic matrix relative to camera1

Comment: @Wang.J Sorry I misunderstood your question and my link is not appropriate.

Comment: @GabrielDevillers that's OK,i found i misunderstood camera matrix with intrinsic matrix ,is them the same?the camera matrix i get by cv2.calibrateCamera() isn't the intrinsic matrix,right?

Comment: @Wang.J it gives you both: the intrinsic matrix of the camera, and as many extrinsic matrix as there are views. (extrinsics are given on the form of R and T). This [tutorial](http://carlos-hernandez.org/papers/fnt_mvs_2015.pdf) explains page 18 the traditional projection model, but there are many other resources online.

Comment: @GabrielDevillers  so i can do RQdecompose to get extrinsic matrix?oh!i finally get it!  thank you!!!XD